# Node js clean architecture cant return response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, microservices, clean-architecture

please I am trying to implement a clean architecture for my node js rest API I studied a tutorial
[Using Clean Architecture for Microservice APIs in Node.js with MongoDB and Express](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnailTcJV_U)
...the goal for me is to adapt the HTTP request and call my controller as a function and return a response

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import httpAdapter from './http_adapter';
import register from './register';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

dotenv.config();

app.post('/account/register', httpAdapter(register));

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port  ${port}`));
```

http_adpter.js

```
export default function httpAdapter(controller) {
    return (req, res) => {
        const httpRequest = {
            body: req.body,
            query: req.query,
            params: req.params,
            ip: req.ip,
            method: req.method,
            path: req.path,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': req.get('Content-Type'),
                Referer: req.get('referer'),
                'User-Agent': req.get('User-Agent'),
            },
        };
        controller(httpRequest)
            .then((httpResponse) => {
                if (httpResponse.headers) {
                    res.set(httpResponse.headers);
                }
                res.type('json');
                res.status(httpResponse.statusCode).send(httpResponse.body);
            })
            .catch((e) =>
                res.status(500).send({ error: 'An unkown error occurred.' })
            );
    };
}
```

register.js

```
export default function register(httpRequest) {
    return () => {
        try {
            const user = httpRequest.body;
            console.log(user);
            return {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                statusCode: 201,
                body: { user },
            };
        } catch (e) {
            // TODO: Error logging
            console.log(e);
            return {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                statusCode: 400,
                body: {
                    error: e.message,
                },
            };
        }
    };
}
```

error

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...[nodemon] starting `babel-node ./src/server.js`
server running on port  5000
TypeError: controller(...).then is not a function
    at C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\src\/http_adapter.js:17:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\tukuyoma\Desktop\odemru\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `babel-node ./src/server.js`
```

Comment: Your controller is not returning a promise. Therefore you cannot use `.then()` on it

Comment: please what can i use..i need help

Comment: @slebetman please what should i do

Comment: for this to work, your `controller` should be a function that return Promise

Comment: @ukuyomatheophilus in `http_adapter.js` you call the function `controller(...)`, where do you import `controller` from? I think you might be misusing a class or something

Comment: out of curiosity: `httpAdapter` is not mentioned in the linked video, nor in that video's author Github repo. Did you use some other source that uses this `httpAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http_adapter.js, Change

```
controller(httpRequest)
        .then((httpResponse) => {
            if (httpResponse.headers) {
                res.set(httpResponse.headers);
            }
            res.type('json');
            res.status(httpResponse.statusCode).send(httpResponse.body);
        })
        .catch((e) =>
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'An unkown error occurred.' })
        );
```

to

```
try{
    const httpResponse =  controller(httpRequest);
    if (httpResponse.headers) {
       res.set(httpResponse.headers);
    }
    res.type('json');
    res.status(httpResponse.statusCode).send(httpResponse.body);
} 
catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'An unkown error occurred.' });
}
```

Should Work if every thing else is fine.